# How to install kvm in Debian (Lenny) over powerpc

Tags: kvm-virtualization, debian-lenny, qemu

I want to install kvm on debian(lenny). I have learnt that packages kvm and qemu-kvm are [not available](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=kvm) for powerpc architecture.
I have found two packages(kvm-source & qemu) and installed it. Now, how do I install kvm. Do I need to install libvirt-kvm as well.

[Edit1]:
Approach1: I downloaded qemu-kvm source code (http://sourceforge.net/projects/kvm/files/qemu-kvm/0.13.0/qemu-kvm-0.13.0.tar.gz/download) , configured

```
#./configure --target-list="ppc-softmmu" 
#make
```

But I am getting this error:

```
CC    ppc-softmmu/virtio-pci.o
~/qemu-kvm-0.13.0/hw/virtio-pci.c: In function 'virtio_pci_mask_notifier':
~/qemu-kvm-0.13.0/hw/virtio-pci.c:436: error: invalid use of undefined 
type 'struct kvm_irq_routing_entry'
~/qemu-kvm-0.13.0/hw/virtio-pci.c:436: error: dereferencing pointer to 
incomplete type
```

Thanks

Comment: What powerpc hardware are you running this on? It matters.

Comment: i have emulated ppc using qemu, and underlying architecture is x86.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KVM on PowerPC is still in its [infant stage](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/PowerPC). I recommend you don't try it unless you're already comfortable with building your own software and kernels.

Comment: I tried qemu-kvm-0.11, and got it installed successfully.